# Why is only one variable displaying on my marker (Google maps api) in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

so i got a Google-maps API in my web server. I can display Markers with the geo locations lat and lng. When u click on the markers you can see some information about it. I give the information "Vorname, Nachname, plz, Adresse" but its only showing "Vorname" ?

How can i display all variables in the marker?

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() 
    {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5167, 9.9167),
            zoom: 6
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        downloadUrl('geomap.php', function(data) 
        {
              var xml = data.responseXML;
              var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
              Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) 
              {
                  var Nachname = markerElem.getAttribute('Nachname');
                  var Vorname = markerElem.getAttribute('Vorname');
                  var Adresse = markerElem.getAttribute('Adresse');
                  var plz = markerElem.getAttribute('plz');
                  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('geolat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('geolong')));

                  var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                  var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                  strong.textContent = Nachname;
                //strong.textContent = Vorname;
                  infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
                  infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                  var text = document.createElement('text');

                  infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                  {
                        map: map,
                        position: point
                  });
                  marker.addListener('click', function() 
                  {
                      infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
              });
          });
      }

      function downloadUrl(url, callback) 
      {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() 
          {
                  if (request.readyState == 4) 
                  {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                  }
          };
          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
      }
          function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because according to your code this is the only thing you've added to node's text content: `strong.textContent = Nachname;`.

If you want to show other vars, it should be something like `strong.textContent = Nachname + ', ' + Vorname + ', ' + plz + ', ' + Adresse;`.

Comment: i was trying to implement multiple strong.textContent , guess i was wrong. thanks !!!